# Did Iran launch a monkey into space and safely return it to Earth?

Tags: history, weapons, iran, space-flight

http://www.chron.com/news/politics/article/Monkey-business-US-unsure-of-Iran-s-space-claims-4249556.php

> The United States expressed doubt on Monday about Iran's claim that
>   it safely returned a monkey from space, saying it is questionable that
>   the monkey survived — or if the flight happened at all.

Doesn't the U.S. monitor rocket launches, especially from a place like Iran? How can they not know if the flight happened at all? NORAD confirmed that North Korea's satellite launch was successful.

Comment: Good luck with proving this either way.  Iran will continue to say they were successful and it will be near impossible for them to convince others that are already skeptical.  The archived photo of the original monkey with the mole supposedly from the supposed failed 2011 attempt.  The mismatch of photos has really hurt the credibility of this space monkey claim.

Comment: You are correct that the United States (and others) monitor countries like Iran for rocket launches; however, none of them are under any obligation to confirm or deny any of the information coming out of Iran.

Comment: This doesn't prove anything about space but [the Iranians do have a history of exaggerating their technological ability](https://medium.com/war-is-boring/knockoff-guns-war-buses-and-other-embarrassing-iranian-weapons-5438d5e45098)

Comment: Do bear in mind that "into space" can imply simply an up-and-down "suborbital" flight.

Comment: @Cruril I think my video proves it.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Iran did at some point successfully launch a monkey into space. And thanks to YouTube you can watch the video

- [Iran's Space Monkey Full High Quality Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xo-7QjxxcDg)
- [Low res version from ISNA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0pv9_m1nDuo)
- [Article from New Scientist](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn22136-iran-space-agency-to-launch-a-monkey-into-space/)

Note, while the Monkey is clearly alive after impact, he seems pretty pissed off and not happy. Monkey after impact:

[image: Monkey]